# Integrate Google login into Phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, google-plus, google-signin

I am trying to intergrate Google+ into my app but nothing works for phonegap. I tried also the plugin of Eddy and it gave me a big error.

So I am asking, is there a good way how to intergrate Google+ into a phonegap app? And if so, is it explained well? Please leave a comment if you know how to intergrate Google+ into a phonegap app.

Comment: show us what you tried and what big error you see. I've done this before by doing an oauth flow with inappbtowser. its not trivial but other s.o. questions and answers alresdy cover it.

Comment: I've used Eddy plugin for Google+ login and It works perfectly. Try testing demo first in basic application - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/tree/master/demo in basic app

Comment: @ZigMandel I tried to install everything new again but that didn't help. Here is the error log btw: http://pastebin.com/hSuKsNEs

Comment: those are tool/build configuration errors you need to google and fix. we cant help, too broad and not about code (unless you show the code that csuses this)

Comment: @ZigMandel What do you mean with tool/build configuration errors? I searched the whole day on Google for a fix but couldn't find anything.

Comment: it might be a library no longer compatible with cordova 4 or 5 for example. that is more about the library itself (a java plugin) than having to do with Google+. Do you have to use a native google+ login? because the google+ js button should work fine in cordova

Comment: @ZigMandel thank you for your answer. I need the Google login, not the Google+ button. At the moment i'm trying to create my own method for connecting with Google+

Comment: by google login i assume their email. thats what the button gives you.